# linq-to-query and contains for an IEnumerable<string>?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have list of strings  `IEnumerable<string> companies` 
containing companies i.e. **mcdonalds, sony inc**.

I want to compare with values in the database. I grab the list from database and in the foreach loop I compare

```
 if (companies.Any(c => c.Contains(name.ToLower())))
 {...}
```

in the database I have companies i.e. **mcdonalds inc, sony**

when searching using "sony" it finds it. When I search using "mcdonalds inc" it doesn't. because of the additional word "inc"

I know I am compare companies.any(contains(mcdonalds inc)) and it doesnt find it.

Any suggesting on how I can extend the if condition to also compare via verse

Comment: Are you sure the space in  'mcdonalds inc' is actually a space? The code you've posted should work as you expect, though I'd wager there's a better solution.

Comment: You'll probably have to filter the list in-memory.  There's not a SQL syntax to see if a value starts with any value in a list without exploding it to multiple conditions (e.g. `WHERE x LIKE 'mcdonalds%' OR x LIKE 'sony%' OR ...` or doing a join on an in-memory table, neither of which is supported by Linq-to-SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Why not compare your list of strings with the database, rather than the database with your list?

```
foreach(var name in list)
{
     if(table.Any(t => SqlMethods.Like(name, string.Format("%{0}%", t.Column))
     { ... 
     }
 }
```

That will capture differences where the names are broadly, but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could call Split before comparing and compare only the first element in the list. In this case you would always discard the 'inc'.
This will of course only work if your problem only happens because you may have suffixes that have to be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how fuzzy you need your string matching to be. You probably can't just remove all occurrences of inc from the string, for example, because a company named "The inc company" or "Inception" will potentially get affected.

For your specific example, you basically need to strip some terms (let's say inc, incorporated, and llc) from the end of the string. Let's also say that there might be more than a single term at the end of the string. You can potentially do this with a regex, something like

```
    Regex termRemover = new Regex("^(?<companyName>.*?)(\\s+(inc|incorporated|llc))*$");
```

which could then be used in your example like

```
    string scrubbedName = termRemover.Match(name.ToLower()).Groups["companyName"].Value;
    if (companies.Any(c => c.Contains(scrubbedName)))
    {...}
```

(plus error checking, etc, dropped here for brevity). The companies list should be scrubbed in the same way prior to use; otherwise your sony inc will never match anything that scrubs to just sony.